# My javascript counter doesnt work on low numbers why?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
const counters = document.querySelectorAll(".counter");
const speed = 1000;

counters.forEach((counter) => {
  const updateCounter = () => {
    const target = +counter.getAttribute("data-target");
    const count = +counter.innerText;

    const increment = target / speed ;

    if (count < target) {
      counter.innerText = Math.floor(count + increment);
      setTimeout(updateCounter, 1);
    } else {
      counter.innerText = target;
    }
  };
  updateCounter();
});
```

This is my javascript codes. Its work perfect for numbers bigger than 1000. But i need to use with lower numbers like "1-2-3-4-5". I couldn't find any solution. Anyone can help me?

I tried to change speed = 1000 top speed = 1 and it worked. But its too fast for animation

Comment: You call `Math.floor()` on the result of `count + increment`. If the increment value is less than 1, the counter won't change.

Comment: So what should i do for to work with every number?

Comment: You either need to make ensure that the value of `increment` is at least 1 (which currently is only true if target >= 1000) or you need to track the current count in a value attribute separate from the innerText, because you are setting innerText to `floor(count+increment)`.  If it's too fast, increase the timeout, as it's currently 1 millisecond.

Comment: Could you create a codepen with what you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little ambiguous which effect you're going for without accompanying HTML/CSS, but I'll take a stab. I think you may want to change

```
const target = +counter.getAttribute("data-target");
const count = +counter.innerText;

const increment = target / speed ;
```

to

```
const target = parseInt(counter.getAttribute("data-target"));
const count = parseInt(counter.innerText);

const increment = Math.ceil(target / speed);
```

I think the problem is:

- If `target < speed`, then you're going to end up with a number less than one.
- Then you add that number to the running count, which starts at zero.
- Then you take Math.floor of the result, which will be zero.

I suspect the function as presented runs a number of times equal to the target number, but it's always changing the number to zero.

See this codepen: https://codepen.io/RyanStreur/pen/PoaBOrX?editors=1010

Comment: its working thank you so much but is too fast. How can i make it slow i change const speed from 1000 to 10000 but nothing change